# Incorrect placement of a MrSid file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, windows, mrsid

I have a map saved as MrSid file which when loaded in QGIS displays as a southern hemisphere location despite being in the UK.  When looking at the .sdw file the northing is positive but in QGIS it shows as negative.  Adding a minus sign to the northing in Notepad and resaving still displays it as a negative value. How can I correct this?

Comment: What CRS is assigned to the layer reported by Rightclick on the layer name -> Properties, CRS tab?

Comment: Thanks AndreJ, The answer is USER:100002 -  * Generated CRS (+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0.999601272 +lon_0=0.999601272 +k=0.999601272 +x_0=0.999601272 +y_0=0.999601272 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.1502,0.247,0.8421,-20.4894 +units=m +no_defs).  Now I find I can change the CRS to OSGB 1936 / British National Grid and use the map in a project but cannot save it as a Gtiff with the OSGB CRS.  Still there is progress for which I am grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The CRS data you report looks rather broken, with the k factor value stored in other parameters where it does not belong.

For reprojecting rasters, you have to use `Raster-> Projections -> Warp`. Reprojection using `Save As` only works for vector data.